# CSS border disappears when padding is more than 0 in ie9 on a "nav ul li" type menu (symfony)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, border, padding

This is my first question here though I've used the site countless times throughout the years. I hate to admit it, but ie9 beat me this time.

Here's my problem. I have a navigation menu pretty standard :
I have some twig in it because it's done in Symfony2

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="main_menu_left">
      <a href="#">Domaines</a>
      <ul>
        {% for domain in domains %}
          <li>
            <a href="{{ path('domains', {'id': domain.id}) }}">{{ domain.name }}</a>
            <ul>
              {% for business in domain.getBusinessesVisibleOrdered %}
                <li>
                  <a href="{{ path('domains', {'id': domain.id}) }}#b{{ business.id }}">{{ business.name }}</a>
                  <ul>
                    {% for job in business.getJobsVisibleOrdered %}
                      <li><a href="{{ job.url }}" target="_blank">{{ job.name }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </li>  
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main_menu_right">
      <a href="mailto:regine.laboure@bnpparibas.com">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main_menu_right">
      <a href="#">Liens utiles</a>
      <ul>
        {% for link in links %}
          <li>
            <a href="{{ link.url }}" target="_blank">{{ link.name }}</a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>  
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And now the CSS

```
nav {
 padding-top: 23px;
 height:30px;
 background-image:url('../images/jds_banner.jpg');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 //border-collapse: collapse;
}

nav .main_menu_left {
 float:left;
 margin-left:50px;
}

nav .main_menu_right {
 float:right;
 margin-right:50px;
}

nav > ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #a6d3b4;
}

nav ul li {
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

nav ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 5px;// <- right here is the problem <-----------------------
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black; 
 white-space: nowrap;
 background-color:white;
}

nav ul li:hover > a {
 color: white;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a, nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > a {
 background-color:#00915a;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:hover > a {
 background-color:#4181c3;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:hover > a {
 background-color:#a1c438;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}

nav > ul ul {
 //box-sizing:border-box;
display: none;
 border:1px solid grey;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
}

nav > ul ul li {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
}

nav > ul ul ul {
 position: absolute; 
 left: 100%; 
 top:0;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to put some padding on the menu, some borders disappear in ie9. And when I say "some", I mean that I can't figure out what the rule is. It can be any of the 4 sides, sometimes 2 sides at once (like left and right, or top and left... still no rule figured out). Most of the UL elements are showing the 4 borders, it's only some of them which aren't.

My current DOCTYPE is `<!DOCTYPE html>` but I had to add this to make the website work `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` because otherwise the site wouldn't work at all in ie9 (in my company the admins have the internet explorer work in some kind of "ie7" default mode or something...)

I've tried to tweak the DOCTYPE but no luck so far.

Anyway, thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Have you tried triggering `haslayout` on `nav > ul ul`, with `zoom:1` or similar?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hello graphicdivine. Nope, but actually I've kinda found the problem (but not the fix), because swtiching back from verdana font to arial solved it. I liked the verdana though ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching back from Verdana font to Arial "solved" the problem, because I don't have any missing border left. The use of the verdana font was not mandatory, but it's still a shame imho.